# Display loading GIF and remove after script has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am lazy loading my Facebook comments plugin, but the plugin takes a while to load. I want the user to know that it's loading by adding a loading GIF. I know how to add the loading GIF, but I don't know how to remove it once the comments plugin has loaded fully. This is what I've tried:

```
<img id="loading" src="/media/assets/loading.gif">
<script>
    function loadAPI() {

        var js = document.createElement('script');
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
        document.body.appendChild(js);
        js.onload=loading();

    }

    window.onscroll = function () {
        var rect = document.getElementById('comments').getBoundingClientRect();
        if (rect.top < window.innerHeight) {
            loadAPI();
            window.onscroll = null;

        }

    }

    //Function used to remove GIF 
    function loading(){
        var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
        loading .parentNode.removeChild(loading); 
    }
    </script>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

<div id="comments" class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

The code I am using, displays the GIF when the user scrolls to the comments section part, and then removes it after all the functions have been invoked. This is not what I want. I want it to get removed after the Faceboook Comments plugin has been displayed. My code removes the GIF a good bit of time prior the plugin displaying. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Try substituting `js.onload=loading;` for `js.onload=loading();` , placing `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";` after `js.onload=loading;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are invoking the loading function when you'd actually need to pass the reference to `js.onload`, so the loading callback gets executed before the Facebook plugin has even finished loading the javascript.
So, change

```
js.onload=loading();
```

to

```
js.onload=loading;
```

Now the gif gets removed when the plugin itself has finished loading, but we can do better than that. The plugin will set a global object `FB` which you can use to subscribe to the render event of the comments ([source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.5)), like so:

```
 FB.Event.subscribe("xfbml.render", function(){
        //The comments are now rendered, remove the image
 });
```

Putting it all together:

```
<img id="loading" src="/media/assets/loading.gif">
<script>
function loadAPI() {

    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
    document.body.appendChild(js);
    js.onload=loading;

}

window.onscroll = function () {
    var rect = document.getElementById('comments').getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.top < window.innerHeight) {
        loadAPI();
        window.onscroll = null;

    }

}

//Function used to remove GIF 
function loading(){
    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function(){
        var loading = document.getElementById('loading');
        loading.parentNode.removeChild(loading); 
    });
}
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```